# Django - avoid captcha , data being submitted by machine through automation

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there any way to avoid captcha to identify the form is submitted by Human? Now a days, captcha is annoying for end user. So I am just curious to know, how to handle at backend?

Answer (score 2):

Some forums ask simple questions for the user:

> What is red backwards?
>
> What is 2 + 3?
>
> Type the word "your" in ALL CAPS
>
> If you have 10 apples and I take away 3, how many do you have?

Just simple questions, but random so that a program cannot easily answer them.

Comment: If so, then we need to build out lots of tricky question on a interval basic to change the question often right? But I would to like to know whether is there any way to identify at backend without any question or captcha ?

Comment: Yes, but you can also make them random by substituting 2, 3, red, your, or apples to different things programmically!

Answer (score 2):

The opposite alternative to a CAPTCHA is a honeypot. This is a field which isn't shown to the user, and shouldn't be filled in: but is given an obvious field name so that automated systems are enticed into filling it in. The back-end then just needs to check that the field contains no value: if it it does contain any value at all, the form is not valid. Django's comments framework uses this technique. It's not particularly reliable, but it does filter out some of the worst bots.

Answer (score 1):

You can partially defend against roaming bots that are not targeting any specific site by creating fields on your form that are totally hidden by CSS.  A human will never fill these fields in, but a bot will not realize that the field is invisible to humans and may fill them in.

This is no protection, however, against a bot that was written to attack your site specifically.  That problem requires some sort of CAPTCHA or another.